# Unable to connect with http://localhost:37265 or http://127.0.0.1:37265

Tags: ios, automation, frank

I am new in iOS application Automation, so far I have set up Frank
framework on my Mac machine. I have followed the tutorial. I have
created a new project and added the Frank skeleton directory to your
app source code.
I have added the Frank server to Frankified target, added CFNetwork
dependency and linker flags. I have turned ON the Accessibility
Inspector on Simulator. Created application successfully RUN on iPhone
simulator. But got "Unable to connect" message on `"http://localhost:37265 or http://127.0.0.1:37265"` page.

I have checked all html/css/js are exists in resource bundle.

```
$curl -v http://localhost:37265
* About to connect() to localhost port 37265 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying fe80::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
macs-Mac-3:Atin mac$
```

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some sort of setup issue with Frank.  The issue is that the HTTP Server is not launching.  If a Frank Cucumber admin/expert sees this and knows whats up please correct anything i said wrong.

This is a workaround/hack solution i discovered, (it may not be the correct solution) but it  will allow you to get Symbiote up and running.

After you have followed the Frank install directions: 
"frank setup" 
"frank build" 
 
"frank launch" 
"frank inspect" 
(Now you get the "Cannot connect to localhost:37625" error/issue.)

1) Open you project in Xcode 
2) In "Project Navigator" Double click your .xcodeproj file. 
3) Select the Target you are trying to test. 
4) Select "Build Phases" tab (at the top) 
5a) Open the drop down arrow menu for "Link Binary With Libraries" 
5b) Click the "+" button and add the following 3 files from the "Frank" directory (This directory should be at the same directory level as your .xcodeproj file): 
    -libCocoaHTTPServer.a 
    -libFrank.a 
    -libShelley.a

6) Run "frank build" 
7) Run "frank launch" 
8) Run "frank inspect" 
9) Voila!  You should nows see Symbiote working.  I hope this works for you.

Comment: This solution does not work on Xcode 5. Any suggestions?

Comment: This did not work for me either. Also XCode 6.2. I guess the problem could be that ios-sim is not added to Accessibility in Privacy & Security. But how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I pass this error by removing `-cal.app` in the `APP_BUNDLE_PATH` then building the application with `-call` target again.